# Always add parameter to url WordPress

Tags: wordpress, url, redirect, parameters

I'm using WordPress to post game and app. Now I want to detect country to display post.

Is there any way to add default parameter into url like that:

> http://demo.com/?geo=VN
>
> http://demo.com/?category/games/?geo=VN

Comment: Means? please explain proper in question.

Comment: When visitor visit my site. I want to detect their country to load app and game by adding geo parameter to current url.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a plugin like [geoplugin](http://www.geoplugin.com/).

Just add the required code in your index and it should work.

It should look something like this:

```
<?php
require_once('geoplugin.class.php');
$geoplugin = new geoPlugin();
$geoplugin->locate();
// create a variable for the country code
$var_country_code = $geoplugin->countryCode;
// redirect based on country code:
if ($var_country_code == "VN") {
header('Location: http://demo.com/?geo=VN');
}
else if ($var_country_code == "AU") {
header('Location: http://demo.com/?geo=AU');
}
else {
header('Location: http://demo.com/');
}
?>
```